# Combining Sass mixin selectors

Tags: sass

I'm trying to figure out if it's at all possible to combine mixin selector strings. I don't believe this is possible in the context of my code, but I could very well be missing something!

Let's say I have the following scss:

```
// Apply a set of rules to input form fields.
@mixin input-form-fields {
    input:not([type="hidden"]),
    textarea {
        @content;
    }
}

// Apply a set of rules to button form fields.
@mixin button-form-fields {
    button, button {
        @content;
    }
}

// Apply a set of rules to select form fields.
@mixin select-form-fields {
    select {
        @content;
    }
}

// Apply a set of rules to all form fields.
@mixin all-form-fields {
    @include input-form-fields {
        @content;
    }
    @include button-form-fields {
        @content;
    }
    @include select-form-fields {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Basically the all-form-fields mixin will call other mixins, thus generating the same set of rules for different selectors.

If I compile the following code:

```
@include all-form-fields {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

I would get something like:

```
input:not([type="hidden"]),
textarea {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

button, 
.button {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

select {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

This is not ideal, I would love it if I could combine those selectors.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could possibly combine the selector strings returned by the 3 different mixins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind storing your selectors in strings, you could define different field types using variables:

```
$input-form-fields: "input:not([type=hidden]), textarea";
$button-form-fields: "button";
$select-form-fields: "select";
```

Your then define your mixins with interpolated strings like so:

```
// Apply a set of rules to input form fields.
@mixin input-form-fields {
    #{$input-form-fields} {
        @content;
    }
}

// Apply a set of rules to button form fields.
@mixin button-form-fields {
    #{$button-form-fields} {
        @content;
    }
}

// Apply a set of rules to select form fields.
@mixin select-form-fields {
    #{$select-form-fields} {
        @content;
    }
}

// Apply a set of rules to all form fields.
@mixin all-form-fields {
    #{$input-form-fields}, 
    #{$button-form-fields}, 
    #{$select-form-fields} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

As a result, `@include all-form-fields` will result in

```
input:not([type=hidden]), textarea,
button,
select {
  margin-bottom: .5em; }
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, after @cimmanon posted the duplicate thread, I came up with the exact solution as you. Thanks for posting the solution.